# Referencing original Height and Width of input

Tags: ffmpeg

By combining scaling and cropping, the example script below scales/crops 30 pixels from each side of the input with the minimum loss of image.

In this example, 720 (original height) must be explicitly stated for the crop. If I use `ih-60` instead of `720-60`, ih will reference the height after the scale filter has been applied, not the original height of the source.

Is it possible to ignore the scale filter (and any other filtering) when referencing height and width.

```
    ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -filter_complex [0]scale=iw-60:-1[S];[S]crop=iw:720-60 out.mp4
```

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work backwards to the original height from the input width and `a` (`iw/ih`):

- the width is 60px less than the original: `orig_w = iw+60`
- the `scale` filter maintains the aspect ratio so `a` is the same before and after the `scale` filter: `orig_h = orig_w/a = (iw+60)/a`

Thus, `crop=iw:(iw+60)/a-60` should do the trick